# Optional with multiple exceptions

Tags: java, spring, option-type

I have the following code snippet that I want to rewrite using optionals

```
public User signup(UserDTO userDTO) throws Exception {
    User user = modelMapper.map(userDTO, User.class);
    
    if (userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).isPresent()) {
        throw new EmailAlreadyUsedException();
    }
    
    if (userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).isPresent()) {
        throw new UsernameAlreadyUsedException();
    }
    
    user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    // set other stuff like encoded password
    userRepo.save(user);
}
```

With optionals, I could come up with following.

```
public User signup(UserDTO userDTO) throws Exception {
    return Optional.of(userDTO)
            .map(u -> modelMapper.map(u, User.class))
            .map(user -> {
                user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                // set other stuff like encoded password

                // check email and username if they exist

                // save
                userRepo.save(user);
                return user;
            }).orElseThrow(Exception::new);
}
```

I am stuck at the part that I cannot throw specific exception depending on username and email. **I can return null if one of them already exist in db and it will cause orElseThrow to work** but with same Exception type. I want two seperate exception for two different case. How can I handle this?

Comment: The method without optionals is much better readable. Think about it. jm2c

Comment: Btw: Your user id is not unique, is it? Creating random UUIDs can create collisions.

Comment: Just don't do it. Your first code snippet is easy to read and understand. `Optional` won't bring you any benefit. And btw: Your code is not safe (you can insert 2 users with the same name and email at the same time). You should simply execute an `INSERT` and let the database do the check for uniqueness. Or put your querys within a transaciton.

Comment: As others have said, your existing code looks cleaner. Unless you’re trying to put “Java 8” on your resume, or get paid by LOC, I’d advise doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the Optional usage which is more Functional.

The thing is that `CheckedException's` were not designed to work with functional style on Java.
The method `.map` of `Optional` receives a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) which does not throws a `Exception`.
Just convert your exceptions to `RuntimeException's` and will work as expected.

...BUT be careful with the instantiating throwables (especially with the param writableStackTrace, configure at false and should be fine), take a look at: [The hidden performance costs of instantiating Throwables](https://normanmaurer.me/blog/2013/11/09/The-hidden-performance-costs-of-instantiating-Throwables/)
.

If you are interested in Functional Programming approach in Java, take a look at [Vavr](https://docs.vavr.io/) too, very nice library and support `CheckedException's` on `Option`.

Comment: Thank for answer. As you said, I should prefer runtime exception.